# Desktop App. in C# - Multiple IE Versions with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webbrowser-control, desktop-application

I'm developing a desktop application, and I want to make a small browser with the possibilities of change the version of WebBrowser (obviously is IE).

I tried with change the registry of my application .exe, for example for this:

**11001 (0x2AF9) or 7000 (0x1B58)**

(**Regkey.SetValue("myApp.exe", 0x1B58, RegistryValueKind.DWord**);

If I do an "alert" of my WebBrowser, i get 11.xxxxx, but this never is changed. 
I'm exhausted of try several things and nothing is working.

Someone has any idea about it?

Sorry for my english.
Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Diego.

**EDIT:**

I tried with this:

```
RegistryKey Regkey32 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
RegistryKey Regkey64 = null;

if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
   Regkey64 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
}

Regkey32.SetValue(Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath), versionIE, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
  Regkey64.SetValue(Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath), versionIE, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}

MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Version.ToString())
```

Return: 11.0.9600.16428 (always)...
Is possible change this version when we are changing the registry?

Comment: This is not an answer but maybe you should check this project before http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer!. I saw it, although I want to make a small emulator with different versions of IE... I don't know if its possible

Comment: Why did you state that it is obviously IE? How were we supposed to know that before you have specified?

Comment: Because when I go to a page like "whatismybrowser" from WebBrowser, says: "Your web browser is: Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 / Internet Explorer 7 Compatibility View, 64-bit Edition, Media Center PC v6.0". I don't have much experience with this, maybe I can be wrong

Comment: According to Microsoft employees IE is only there do download a real browser

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl - it's a very good writeup.